# Unable to call MS Graph API Call with multiple filters in react app

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api

When I try to call ms graph API call using react with filters getting the below error. If  I remove the filters, its works fine.
Error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)enter code here
getGraphClient(result.accessToken)
.api('/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}?
expand=fields')
.filter('id eq 1 or Title eq ??')
.responseType(ResponseType.RAW)
.get()

```
    request URL is https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/lists/{listid}/items?$expand=fields?$filter=fields/Id%20eq%201%20,fields($select=Id,Title)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a typo in an endpoint before filter parameter: change `?$filter` with `&$filter`.

And it should work if you specify `($select)` options in `expand` param, so your request URL would look like:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/lists/{listid}/items?$expand=fields($select=Id,Title)&$filter=fields/Id%20eq%201%20
```

Comment: Hi Kadis, I updated request but still same error i am getting in react application, HTTPMessageHandler.ts:29 
 GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/lists/{listid}/items?$expand=fields($select=Id,Title)&$filter=fields/Id%20eq%201%20 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Is it your request missing slash before site-id value or it's a typo in a comment? Can you retrieve error message for more detailed description in your app or if you try it in Postman?

Comment: Also, pay attention, that to filter on some column in query, it should be indexed. If it's not you can add a header Prefer=HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly, but it will fail anyway for large lists without index (more than 5000 items)